# Oledb update-command with parameters not working on access-db

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbparameter

I have a problem in my c#-application. I try to update an access-database via oledb-connection.

Here is the schema of the table:

[image]

Here is the function i am using:

```
public override int Update(string tableName, Action<ISqlParameterizer> actionSqlParameterizerUpdate, Action<ISqlParameterizer> actionSqlParameterizerWhere)
{
    var commandText = $"update {tableName} set @update where @where";

    var whereBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var updateBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var whereParameterizer = SqlParameterizer.CreateFrom(this);
    var updateParameterizer = SqlParameterizer.CreateFrom(this);

    actionSqlParameterizerWhere?.Invoke(whereParameterizer);
    actionSqlParameterizerUpdate?.Invoke(updateParameterizer);

    List<IDbDataParameter> parameterList = new List<IDbDataParameter>();

    foreach (var whereParameter in whereParameterizer.GetParameters())
    {
        whereBuilder.Append($" and {whereParameter.ParameterName} = @{whereParameter.ParameterName}");
        parameterList.Add(whereParameter);
    }
    foreach (var updateParameter in updateParameterizer.GetParameters())
    {
        updateBuilder.Append($", {updateParameter.ParameterName} = @{updateParameter.ParameterName}");
        parameterList.Add(updateParameter);
    }

    commandText = commandText.Replace("@where", whereBuilder.ToString().Substring(4));
    commandText = commandText.Replace("@update", updateBuilder.ToString().Substring(1));

    return base.ExecuteNonQuery(commandText, parameterList.ToArray());
}
```

The commandtext-property looks like this:

> update MY_TABLE set  MY_COLUMN = @MY_VALUE where  SOME_COLUMN = @SOME_VALUE

The datatype of SOME_COLUMN is **numeric**, the datatype of MY_COLUMN is **Memo**.

Both parameters are oledbtype integer. I tried to add the parameter for MY_COLUMN as an string, so the parameter is VarWChar, but that makes no difference.

After running the command nothing happens, no rows get updated. When i enter the commandtext in Access itself and execute the statement. Access askes for the values of my parameters. I enter my values and the rows get updated.

Why does this not work with my oledb-connection?

---

The problem seems to be located at the SqlContext-class i am using.

Using a normal OleDbConnection:

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION_STRING_ACCESS))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = $"UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_COLUMN = @MY_VALUE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = @SOME_VALUE";
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("MY_COLUMN", "MY_VALUE"));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("SOME_COLUMN", 1));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

works just fine...

Using my class:

```
using (var accessContext = SqlContext.Create(CONNECTION_STRING_ACCESS, SqlProvider.AccessSql))
{
    accessContext.Update("MY_TABLE", update => {
        update.Add("MY_COLUMN", "MY_VALUE");
    }, where => {
        where.Add("SOME_COLUMN", 1);
    });
}
```

doesn't work...

I have compared the commandtext-objekt and the parameter-objects of both versions and they are the same (except for the value of "MY_COLUMN", otherwise i could not recognize if the row gets updated). (i can not add the screenshots, because stack overflow says "the format is not supported", the funny thing is, that i was able to add my first screenshot (.bmp) without problem, when i try to add the second screenshot (.bmp) the error is shown ).

Anny suggestions what is causing the problem?

Comment: No errors being thrown?

Comment: No... the rows just don't get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters are not in the correct order. These 2 loops should be switched in the order they appear in the code.

This matters, the [OleDbCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) does not use named parameters. They are ordinal based on the position they occur in the sql statement.

[Documentation - OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbCommand_Parameters)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used.
>
> ...
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text

---

Your code:

```
// should occur 2nd
foreach (var whereParameter in whereParameterizer.GetParameters())
{
    whereBuilder.Append($" and {whereParameter.ParameterName} = @{whereParameter.ParameterName}");
    parameterList.Add(whereParameter);
}

// should occur 1st
foreach (var updateParameter in updateParameterizer.GetParameters())
{
    updateBuilder.Append($", {updateParameter.ParameterName} = @{updateParameter.ParameterName}");
    parameterList.Add(updateParameter);
}
```