# Update statement does nothing

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

When I enter a number in the `ChbBeds_numericUpDown` and click on the "Update" button, it says "Data Updated", but nothing changes in the database

```
private void ChbUp_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        string statement = "UPDATE ChamberXPavilions SET Beds count = @beds_count WHERE Pav_name = @pav_name AND Chamber_number = @chamber_number";

        cmd = new OleDbCommand(statement, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pav_name", Chbpav_comboBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chamber_number", Chb_numericUpDown.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@beds_count", ChbBeds_numericUpDown.Value);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("Data updated");
        showdata();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is the SQL statement wrong ?

Comment: Does the column "Beds count" really contain a space character? Then you need to enclose it in square brackets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oledb update-command with parameters not working on access-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648299/oledb-update-command-with-parameters-not-working-on-access-db)

Comment: Update only works if the row(s) already exist in the database.  If the rows do not exist than you have to use INSERT.  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns the number of rows changed.  When using UPDATE and you get zero rows changed than use INSERT.  Or do the opposite.  First try Insert and if you get zero rows changed than rows already exist and then you have to try UPDATE.

Comment: @KlausGütter It's Beds_count in my code, its just just spellcheck correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to SQL Server, the OleDB provider for MS Access does **NOT** work with named parameters - instead, it uses **positional** parameters.

In your case, you have a SQL statement

```
UPDATE ChamberXPavilions 
SET Beds count = @beds_count 
WHERE Pav_name = @pav_name AND Chamber_number = @chamber_number
```

so you need to also provide the parameters in the same order - first `@beds_count`, then `@pav_name` and finally `@chamber_number`.

So try this for providing the parameter values:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(statement, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@beds_count", ChbBeds_numericUpDown.Value);    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pav_name", Chbpav_comboBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chamber_number", Chb_numericUpDown.Value);
```

Now, your `UPDATE` statement *should* get the proper values and should now work

Comment: thanks it worked, you guys are life savers in this website keep it up